# aCalendar does not show all my events

Tags: google-calendar

I am using [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar&hl=en), with google accounts.

Recently, one of my calendars started showing only a few events. None in the past, only a few in the future.

The stock calendar app works fine.

I've tried emptying cache, reinstalling the app, still not working.

I need help to find where I should look next. No obvious setting to be found in my Google Calendar.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link to the app on Goole PlayStore. Otherwise it is not clear which app you are talking about.

Comment: For questions or problems see our new help system at [https://acalendar.tapirapps.de](https://acalendar.tapirapps.de) or contact our support at support@tapirapps.de